# Xamarin chart(график)

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, диаграммы

Необходимо отобразить график. Например как выглядит график синуса. Я был сильно удивлен, что среди компонентов нету элемента **chart**.
Пошарил по интернету, предлагают установить microсharts
Какие ещё есть варианты? Желательно которые максимально похожи на работу с стандартным chart из c# .NET

Comment: Вот неплохой [вебинар](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Lb7Qabj9xA) про 10 Xamarin Charts.

Comment: @Bulson в вебинаре используется библиотека syncfusion , которая стоит 995$

Comment: О, не знал... :)

Answer (score 0):

Важно отметить, что пока что нету chart, который поддерживался бы всеми платформами
Мой выбор пал на Crosslight Charting
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]